# Implementing an accuracy metric in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the examples in the TensorFlow documentation, specifically [example 1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/), where the metric is assigned as follows:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

I was wondering: how do I implement a different accuracy metric. For example MAP(mean average precision). Assuming that I have a function:

```
import numpy as np

def accuracyMAP(y_pred, y_real):

    def __precision_at_k(r, k):   
        r = np.asarray(r)[:k] != 0
        return np.mean(r)

    temp_sorted = y_real[np.argsort(-y_pred)]
    till = np.where(temp_sorted==1)
    r = temp_sorted[:till[0]+1]
    return __precision_at_k(r, len(r))
```

A way to go through is to make the predictions and pass it the `mean_precision_scorce` function:

```
for batch_xs in x:
    y_pred = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch_xs})
    acc = accuracyMAP(y_true, y_pred)
```

where both y_true and y_predicted are converted to numpy arrays.But is there a way to do it similar with the example of Tensorflow? Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

If your `mean_precision_score` function can operate on TF tensors, you can simply do: `acc = mean_precision_score(y_true, y)` and later `sess.run(acc, ...)`.

Comment: you mean something like `score = accuracy(y_true,y); mean_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(score)` i got an error `Input 'strides' of 'StridedSlice' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'begin'`. Tried to use also `tf.cast` but didnt find a way to pass that.

Comment: You need to show the code for your `accuracy` function to make it possible to understand where the error comes from.